# Laravel - JQuery keyup only works when parent_id is 1 in Laravel json

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I am trying to make my dropdown load value on textbox on change.

```
CREATE TABLE `appraisal_goal_types` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `max_score` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

table diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfVuJ.png

```
CREATE TABLE `appraisal_goals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `goal_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `employee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Controller

```
public function findScore(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;

    $identities                     = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first()->id;      
    $child  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$request->id)->first();

    $parentid  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('parent_id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$request->id)->first()->parent_id;

   if(empty($child))
   {
       abort(404);
   }  
   $weightedscore = 0;
   $weightedscore = DB::table('appraisal_goals')->select(DB::raw("SUM(weighted_score) as weighted_score"))->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities)->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('parent_id', $parentid)->get();
   $maxscore = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('max_score')->find($child->parent_id);
    return response()->json([
        'maxscore' => $maxscore->max_score,
        'weightedscore' => $weightedscore
    ]);        
}
```

Also I have routes/web.php

```
Route::get('get/findScore','Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@findScore')->name('get.scores.all');
```

view

```
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
              <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                  <option hidden value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div> 

<input type="hidden" id="max_score" class="form-control" >
<input type="hidden" id="weighted_score" class="form-control" value="0" >


<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Weight(%):<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <input  type="number" name="weighted_score" id="total_weighted_score" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control" max="120" onkeyup="checkScore(this.value)">
 </div>
</div>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '#goal_type', function() {
            var air_id =  $(this).val();

            var a = $(this).parent();

            var op = "";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{ route('get.scores.all') }}',
                data: { 'id': air_id },
                dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.maxscore);
                    console.log(data.weightedscore);
                     $('#max_score').val(data.maxscore);
                     $('#weighted_score').val(data.weightedscore);
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkScore(value){
   let max_score = $("#max_score").val();
   let weighted_score = $("#weighted_score").val();
   let sumValue = parseInt(weighted_score) + parseInt(value);

   if (sumValue > max_score) {
     alert("sum value is greater than max score");
     $("#total_weighted_score").val('');
      return false;
     }
   }
</script> to
```

What I want to achieve is that on keyup, for a particular employee, I want the application #weighted_score with the current value in total_weighted_score. Then if the total is more than #max_score, it should display this message:

```
alert("sum value is greater than max score");
```

My observation is that it works fine where the parent_id is 1 but fails for other ones (5 and 6).

Why and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<input  type="number" name="weighted_score" id="total_weighted_score" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control" max="120">

<script>
$("input[name=weighted_score]").on('blur keyup keydown change paste',function(){


   var value = $(this).value();
   let max_score = $("#max_score").val();
   let weighted_score = $("#weighted_score").val();
   let sumValue = parseInt(weighted_score) + parseInt(value);

   if (sumValue > max_score) {
     alert("sum value is greater than max score");
     $("#total_weighted_score").val('');
      return false;
     }


})

</script>
```